# How simply convert collection of one type to collection of another type

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say i have collection `IList<Items> items = GetItems();` 
I want to convert that collection in to collection of `MyDbSet<Items>`

MyDbSet declared like that: `public class MyDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T> where T : class`

How can i do that with the less amount of code, possibly it is better to go with linq?

Comment: That depends on the target collection type. Some have `Add`, some `AddRange`, some a constructor taking an `IEnumerable<T>` and some use a specific helper method like `ToArray()`.

Comment: `MyDbSet` has just `Add`, no constructors

Comment: `ICollection<T>.Add` is probably the closest you get to a generic approach, but it'll fail for immutable collections and arrays.

Comment: i just dont want to loop it through in foreach, just want to do it in less lines as possible using linq

Comment: Less lines != better code.

Answer (score 1):

For collections that support `ICollection<T>.Add` you could write a helper method like this:

```
public static TCollection CreateCollection<TCollection,TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> seq)
    where TCollection:ICollection<TElement>, new
{
    var coll=new TCollection();
    foreach(var element in seq)
      coll.Add(element);
    return coll;
}
```

which is used like:

```
var coll = CreateCollection<MyDbSet<T>, T>(seq);
```

But personally I'd rather write an `AddRange(seq)` extension method and then use it like:

```
var coll = new MyDbSet<T>();
coll.AddRange(seq);
```

Comment: You missed `where TCollection : new`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way other than just loop over the source collection and call `Add` on your `MyDbSet` class instance, however it can be hidden in custom extension method:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static MyDbSet<T> ToMyDbSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class
    {
        var collection = new MyDbSet<T>();

        foreach (var item in source)
            collection.Add(item);

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IList<Items> items = GetItems();

MyDbSet<Items> itemsSet = items.ToMyDbSet();
```